# Clarification about Operational Support System

Tags: ansible, automation

I just started my career as a  BA. As the first task, I have to study about operational support systems like ansible tower. I could not find any references to study about this. What are the similar operational support systems to ansible tower? Are there any references to study about them.

Answer (score 2):

The [Wikipedia definition of Operational Support System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operations_support_system) (OSS) makes it sound like a term of art from telecommunication companies.  I haven't seen this come up in systems administration over many years of working in this area.  The top vendors in the OSS space are Ericsson, Nokia, and Huawei.  I never see those guys trying to help me manage cloud deployments, so I don't feel there's much overlap with what Ansible Tower does.

Ansible Tower provides a GUI for working with the anisble configuration management tool.  While this provides similar functionality to what it seems an Operational Support System to be, I doubt Ansible Tower is being used as an OSS by anyone.  It wasn't mentioned in any of the product comparisons I googled for OSS vendors.

Tools similar to Ansible Tower would be in categories like deployment tools or infrastructure visualization.  A few examples of these:

- [rundeck](https://www.rundeck.com/)
- [DeployHub](https://www.deployhub.com/)
- [Foreman](https://www.theforeman.org/)

There's also overlap with CI/CD tools.